# Shell script [Expected end of line, etc. but found unknown token]

Tags: shell

I'm trying to build a Synergy AutoStart script as per [this article](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/autostart.html), the shell is giving me the error

> **Syntax Error**
>
> Expected end of line, etc. but found
>   unknown token

Here is the script I'm working on...

```
#!/bin/sh
. /etc/rc.common

run=(/usr/local/bin/synergyc -n $(hostname -s) -1 -f 192.168.0.108)

KeepAlive ()
{
 proc=${1##*/}

 while [ -x "$1" ]
 do
  if ! ps axco command | grep -q "^${proc}\$"
  then
   "$@"
  fi
   sleep 3 
 done
}

StartService ()
{
 ConsoleMessage "Starting Synergy"
 KeepAlive "${run[@]}" &
}

StopService ()
{
 return 0
}

RestartService ()
{
 return 0
}

RunService "$1"
```

And when the error is thrown, the "period" is highlighted on this line `. /etc/rc.common`

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: The code you've posted is not AppleScript, it's a shell script.  Where the directions in your link talk about creating a "script," they just mean a text file.

Comment: @rock: What program did you use to write the script?

Comment: @Isaac, I didn't realize that... what extension do I use [.txt]? @outis, I used AppleScript Editor.

Comment: Thanks guys... I just removed the extension all together and run Dos2Unix to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try dos2unix on the file if you've been editing on a windows machine.

Comment: It was a combination of @Isaac's answer above as well as yours.  Thanks... working now.

Answer (score 1):

Note the particular problem was [line endings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations). Unixen use the [line-feed](http://wps.com/projects/codes/index.html#LF) character (LF), Macs traditionally use [carriage-return](http://wps.com/projects/codes/index.html#CR) (CR), MS OSs use CR LF. With the wrong line-endings, the shell sees the entire shell script as as single line; CRs aren't considered whitespace and are [token](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_(parser)#Token)ized. Hence the message that the shell "expected end of line, [...] but found unknown token". Running the script through dos2unix fixes the line endings.

Read Apple's "[Shell Scripting Primer](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/Introduction/Introduction.html)". Among other things, it tells you how to use Text Edit.app (and pico and nano, from the command line) to write shell scripts. Alternatively, learn to use [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/) or [Vim for OS X](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/).

Comment: The version of MacVim to which you linked is fairly old.  The current (though unrelated) MacVim is at http://code.google.com/p/macvim/